# How to make a Magic Mirror module run at specific time everyday?

Tags: javascript, magic-mirror

I'm trying to build a a Magic Mirror module. It is supposed to show my favorite restaurant's daily menu on the screen. The menu is stored in the `menu.txt` file in this structure:

```
{"Monday": ["Food 1", "Food 2", "Food 3"]}
{"Tuesday": ["Food 4", "Food 5", "Food 6"]}
{"Wednesday": ["Food 7", "Food 8", "Food 9"]}
{"Thursday": ["Food 10", "Food 11", "Food 12"]}
{"Friday": ["Food 13", "Food 14", "Food 15"]}
```

The food is served until 14 on weekdays, so I want the module to be reloaded exactly at 14:01, and shows the next day's menu. Like this:

```
If it is a Monday, only the second line of the text file will be shown.
If it is a Tuesday, only the third line of the text file will be shown.
If it is a Wednesday, only the fourth line of the text file will be shown.
If it is a Thursday, only the fifth line of the text file will be shown.
Otherwise, only the first line of the text file will be shown.
```

I'm new with JS, and can't figure this out. This is the `config/config.js` entry:

```
{
  module: "weeklyText",
  position: "top_center",
}
```

and this is the module's code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

Module.register("weeklyText", {
  defaults: {
    filePath: "modules/weeklyText/menu.txt",
    reloadInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours in milliseconds
    showKeyInBold: true,
  },

  start: function () {
    var self = this;

  
    self.updateText();
    self.updateDom();

    // Calculate the delay until 14:01
    const delay = self.calculateDelay();

    // Set a timeout for the first run at 14:01
    setTimeout(function () {
      // Run the first update
      self.runUpdate();

      // Set an interval for subsequent updates every 24 hours
      setInterval(function () {
        self.runUpdate();
      }, self.config.reloadInterval);
    }, delay);
  },

  runUpdate: function () {
    const now = new Date();
    const currentDay = now.getDay();
    const targetLine = (currentDay >= 1 && currentDay <= 4) ? currentDay + 1 : 1;

    this.updateText(targetLine);
    this.updateDom();
  },

  calculateDelay: function () {
    const now = new Date();
    const targetTime = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 14, 1, 0, 0);
    let delay = targetTime - now;

    if (delay < 0) {
      delay += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // If it's already past 14:01, set the delay for the next day
    }

    return delay;
  },

  updateText: function (targetLine) {
    var self = this;

    // Read text from the file
    try {
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, self.config.filePath);
      const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8");

      // Parse each line as JSON
      const lines = fileContent.split("\n").filter((line) => line.trim() !== "");
      const parsedData = lines.map((line) => JSON.parse(line));

      // Find the target line based on the day of the week
      const targetEntry = parsedData.find((entry, index) => index + 1 === targetLine);

      if (targetEntry) {
        const key = self.config.showKeyInBold ? `<strong>${targetEntry.key}</strong>` : targetEntry.key;
        const listItems = targetEntry.value.map((item) => `<p>${item}</p>`).join("");
        self.config.text = `<div>${key}${listItems}</div>`;
      } else {
        self.config.text = "No entry for the current day.";
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error reading or parsing text file:", error.message);
      self.config.text = "Error reading or parsing text file.";
    }
  },

  // Override dom generator.
  getDom: function () {
    var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.className = "thin xlarge bright";
    wrapper.innerHTML = this.config.text;
    return wrapper;
  },
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and nothing is shown on the display. What am I doing wrong?